# Limit and reduce size of xDB in Sitecore 9.2+

Tags: xdb

In the Sitecore 9.2 release it is mentioned in [this post](http://www.pieterbrinkman.com/2019/08/12/sitecore-9-2-enhancements-highlights/) that a new feature is available:

> Limit and reduce size of xDB

I haven't been able to find how to enable this in official documentation. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Is this related? https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/managing-the-size-of-your-reporting-data.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not from a configuration standpoint.

> Before Sitecore 9.2 it was not easy to remove old data that isn’t
> relevant anymore. (Unless you are using a 3rd party integration)
>
> A new API has been made available to maintain and purge data withing
> xDB. ***This can help to reduce the size of the xDB database*** and gives
> you more control on what data you want to keep. It is possible to
> write a custom tool to periodically and automatically remove xDB data.

and

> In version 9.2 and later, xConnect allows you to delete contacts and
> all associated data in xDB if you choose to. So, you have the ability
> to remove the data that isn't useful to you anymore.
> https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-platform/en/deleting-contacts-and-interactions-from-the-xdb.html
>
> But, you need to do this by writing code, and so you would need to
> work with your Sitecore architect and developers to carefully plan
> this out for your implementation. And again, this is only an option
> for the newer versions of the platform.

References:

1. [https://www.blastic.be/articles/discover-what's-new-in-sitecore-9.2/](https://www.blastic.be/articles/discover-what%27s-new-in-sitecore-9.2/)
2. https://sitecoreart.martinrayenglish.com/2020/06/sitecore-xdb-extending-xconnect-to.html
3. https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/sitecore-experience-platform/en/deleting-contacts-and-interactions-from-the-xdb.html